# Why is this nested recursive call in a match pattern not working?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I wrote a simple function to replicate every
element in a list a given amount of times.

```
    let rec replicate l n = 
        let rec f l n acc = 
            match l with 
            |[]->acc
            |x::xs->f xs n (let rec h e n acc = if n = 0 then acc else h e (n-1) (e::acc) in h x n acc) 
        in List.rev (f l n [])
```

This is working as Im calling `f` and set its accumulator to the result of the helper method `h`

But why is the following method not working?

```
let rec replicate l n = 
    let rec f l n acc = 
        match l with 
        |[]->acc
        |x::xs->(let rec h e n acc = if n = 0 
        then f xs n acc else h e (n-1) (e::acc) 
        in h x n acc) 
    in f l n [];;
```

Here I'm calling the outer function `f` in case `n=0`.

Here are the results for the same call with the two functions:

1. replicate ["a"; "b"; "c"] 3;;

- : string list = ["a"; "a"; "a"; "b"; "b"; "b"; "c"; "c"; "c"]

2. replicate ["a"; "b"; "c"] 3;;

- : string list = ["a"; "a"; "a"]

Comment: The second function has a syntax error

Comment: There's one extra closed parens that shouldn't be there: `let rec h e n acc = (if n = 0) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second line of

```
let rec h e n acc = 
  if n = 0 then f xs n acc
  else h e (n-1) (e::acc) 
in h x n acc
```

you are calling `f xs n acc` with `n=0` and not the initial value of `n`.

As a general advice, it is better to not nest recursive function definitions. Indeed, this limits the complexity of your function control flow.
For instance, with

```
let rec repeated_append n x l =
  if n = 0 then l
  else repeated_append (n-1) x (x::l)

let replicate n l = 
  let rec replicate_aux n acc l = 
    match l with 
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | x::xs-> replicate_aux n (repeated_append n x acc) xs
  in
  replicate_aux n [] l
```

I am guaranteed that the recursive functions `repeated_append` and `replicate_append` only call themselves in their body. In particular, there is no possibility of `h` calling `replicate` or `f` which makes the function easier to read.

Comment: Given `repeated_append`, you could also define `replicate` quite simply as:  `let replicate n l = List.(l |> map (fun x -> repeated_append n x []) |> flatten)`

Comment: If we are using functions from the `List` module, it is better to use `List.concat_map` directly.

Comment: Fair. Early in the morning for me. Also stuck on an older OCaml version at this workstation.

Comment: Regardless of the question of the most optimal stdlib function to use, your example is a good illustration that defining useful helpers functions make it easier to write more elaborate functions by composing small functions together.